How to move data from next row to top automatically after clearing?
I want row 35 (32) data move to cell B4 automatically after clearing data from row 1 to 34.
Private Sub ClearContents_Click()
    Range("B4:J34").ClearContents
End Sub

I am still learning VBA. So, I don't know what to put.
I tried Rows.Delete Range("4:34").
It didn't work.

The numbers don't add up. Could you fix the typos ((32) and 1 to 34)? Also, explain which cells should be shifted where to, e.g., after deleting B4:J34, B35:J65 or K4:S34 should 'fill the gap' which could be covered with Range("B4:J34").Delete xlShiftUp or Range("B4:J34").Delete xlShiftToLeft respectively.

32 is the number that I put in row 35. uploaded a picture, somehow it didn't upload.

The Rows method returns a Range object, and "4:34" isn't a valid argument to the Delete method of Range.
Range("4:34").Delete should do what you intend.
